# Why is the new Ubuntu Monospace font only available for 11.04?

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-font-family

... and not for Lucid (10.04)?

I just checked it here on two of my machines, one running lucid and one running natty. And yes, I am approved member of this special group on launchpad.

**Addition**: I'm **not** asking *how* to get this font ... because I already got it ... yes for lucid too, i just copied the contents of the natty package onto my lucid installation. I ask for the "*Why?*".

Comment: I'm asking, how did you get the font?

Comment: @Thomas Boxley  http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/ubuntu-font-monospace-variant-hits-beta-testing-ppa/

Comment: Yes, see Rinzwind. I was very excited about the new font long time before the monospace variant was out. And when i saw they are working on it, i immediatly applied to become member of the ubuntu font family group. Now i am and have access to the private repo.

Comment: Yes, I had applied for the original Ubuntu font beta, so I reckon I am eligible to get this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because the font in question is in beta, and it will get sufficient testing on the current version of Ubuntu.  This does not necessarily mean that the font will never be seen on Lucid.

Comment: **dAnjou:** It's really pleasing to find people wanting to test on older versions of the Ubuntu operating system.  As James notes, there tend to be more likely to be beta-testers running the recent and in-development version.  Good news though, now that you've picked it up: I've now pushed the `ttf-ubuntu-font-family` package with the monospace betas to `ppa:ubuntu-font-beta-testing/ppa` for both lucid (10.04) and maverick (10.10) aswell.  Happy testing!  Please test and report any issues or concerns that you find and many thanks for the tip-off!

Comment: this info is now out of date, since the monospace font has been released. however, it is still unclear if it is packaged for lucid anywhere